# x220 - Ubuntu 14.04 - Screen dims on login and logout

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I have a Lenovo x220, i5 with BIOS 1.40.

I have a issue when booting into Ubuntu to login and when I log out where the screen dims and is barely visible until I increase the brightness.

I had a issue with GRUB shortly before, assuming it was related (and I did not have any required data on the machine) I formatted my drive and reinstalled Ubunutu. However the issue persists even after the fresh install.

I have checked BIOS as other forums suggest and there is no brightness settings in there.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop running without any issues with 14.04 and now 16.04 my BIOS is latest 1.42 Check the condition of your battery and see if it has enough life left. Also if you want to stick to 14.04 download and install latest 14.04.4 or better install latest 16.04 that runs the system a bit cooler and quite quick.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, checked the battery all is okay (have dual boot with windows and everything okay in windows too). I checked my ubuntu edition it is 14.04.4. May give 16.04 a try but trying to stick to 14.04 as it matches some servers I work with so I can use same packages etc

Comment: The problem is quite strange as I have been running Ubuntu on this since the day I brought this around 2011 December.

Comment: Yes, it is really strange. It was working properly last week, the only thing that has changed it the BIOS has been updated, but I can not see anything in there that would cause such issues. :(

Comment: I downgraded BIOS to 1.28 when I was on 1.40 and issue persisted. 
So just flashed BIOS to 1.42 and booted in Ubuntu and logout a couple of times and issue seems to be gone for now atleast. Really weird - anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Good it worked out for you, don't forget to install TLP, I get 5+ hours of battery life on my regular battery pack.